# Can I 'match' values in 2 arrays and then use the subsequent 'matched' value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, url, browser-detection

I'm trying to achieve the following though with my intermediate JavaScript skills I'm not sure if this is possible.

This is related in part to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992964/how-do-i-display-a-certain-image-based-on-matching-a-value-in-an-array).

Now I have 2 arrays

a) Has the various language in (e.g. "en-GB", "fr", "de" etc)
b) Has a suffix of a URL based on the browser language above (e.g. "fr/","de/","uk/")

What I am trying to achieve is:

1) User hits a page, browser detects which browser it is using from the array (a)
2) Depending on what the browser is based on (a), it then searches through (b) and if they match, e.g. if the language is "fr" it will use the suffix "fr/" from the array in (b).
3) It will then add this suffix to a top level domain (which is always constant)
Is this even possible to achieve (I'm sure it is)? Can it be done purely via JavaScript (or JQuery)? How would I go about doing this?

Here's some of the code I have so far:

```
var IAB_Array = new Array("de-at","nl-be","fr-be","da","de","hu","en-ie","ga","es","fr","it","nl","no","pl","en","en-GB","en-US","en-gb","en-us"); //language array
var IAB_suffix = new Array("at/","be-nl/","be-fr","den/","de/","hu/","ie/","es/","fr/","it/","nl/","nor/","pl/","uk/"); //URL suffix Array
var IAB_lang = "en-GB"; //default language
var IAB_link = "http://www.mysitegoeshere/";

if(navigator.browserLanguage) IAB_lang = navigator.browserLanguage; //change lang if detection supported
if(window.navigator.language) IAB_lang = window.navigator.language; //change lang if detection supported

function IAB_Lang_detect () { //execute search
for (var i=0;i<IAB_Array.length;i++) {
    if(IAB_Array[i]==IAB_lang) {
        document.write(IAB_Array[i]); //output matched array value
        }
}
return false;
}

var IAB_URL = "<a href="+IAB_link+IAB_suffix[1]+">"+IAB_link+IAB_suffix[1]+"</a>"; //this is the resulting URL

document.write(IAB_URL);
IAB_Lang_detect ();
```

I hope someone can help as I'm a little confused! It's more so the matching the values from the 2 arrays and then subsequently selecting the correct suffix that I'm having trouble with.

Thanks

Comment: how are we supposed to get the two array match? Meaningly, how can we find that `"fr-be"` should be `"be-fr"` in the second array?

Comment: Yet, if the only point is to add a slash `/` at the end of the language, that would be probably easier to do some concatenation instead of searching through arrays

Comment: @JMax: If you look at the values, there seem to be other differences, not just the slash.

Comment: Yes apologies, I neglected to mention that for some languages like english there are many variations, but ultimately the suffix will be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var lang_map = {
        "de-at": "at/",
        "nl-be": "be-nl/",
        "fr-be": "be-fr",
        "da": "den/",
        "de": "de/",
        "hu": "hu/",
        "en-ie": "ie/",
        "ga": "ie/",
        "es": "es/",
        "fr": "fr/",
        "it": "it/",
        "nl": "nl/",
        "no": "nor/",
        "pl": "pl/",
        "en": "uk/",
        "en-GB": "uk/",
        "en-US": "uk/",
        "en-gb": "uk/",
        "en-us": "uk/"
    },
    lang = (navigator && navigator.browserLanguage) || (window.navigator && window.navigator.language) || "en-GB";
    window.location = "http://www.mysitegoeshere/" + lang_map[lang];
}());
```

Comment: fair, I was copying from his code, wasn't sure if he was using something that had a global navigator object defined.

Comment: `@Auto`: True, if the whole thing's inside some function with a local `navigator`.

Answer (score 0):

I probably wouldn't use arrays for this at all. You can use an object:

```
var IABInfo = {
    "de-at": "at/",
    "ln-be": "be-nl/",
    // ...and so on
};
```

Then index directly into that object:

```
var value = IABInfo[IABLang]; // Where IABLang contains a string, like "de-at"
```

So:

```
var suffix = IABInfo[IABLang];
if (suffix) { // Did we have it?
    document.write(suffix);
}
```

This works because all JavaScript objects are free-form key/value *maps*. Here's a simpler example:

```
var lifeTheUniverseAndEverything = {
    answer: 42,
    question: "?"
};
```

You can look up a property either using dotted notation with a literal, or by using square bracket (`[]`) notation with a string. So all four of these output exactly the same thing:

```
// 1. Dotted notation with a literal:
console.log("The answer is " + lifeTheUniverseAndEverything.answer);

// 2. Bracketed notation with a string
console.log("The answer is " + lifeTheUniverseAndEverything["answer"]);

// 3. The string needn't be a literal, it can come from a variable...
var name = "answer";
console.log("The answer is " + lifeTheUniverseAndEverything[name]);

// 4. ...or indeed any expression:
console.log("The answer is " + lifeTheUniverseAndEverything["a" + "n" + "swer"]);
```

So by making your IAB info a map in an object literal, you can make it much easier to look things up: Just use bracketed notation with the desired language code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it differently and use an object:

```
var IAB_Object = { "it-It": "it/", "en-Gb": "en/" ....}

if(IAB_Object.hasOwnProperty(IAB_lang)){
   //you have a match, the suffix is
   var suffix = IAB_Object[IAB_lang];
}else{
   //you don't have a match use a standard language
}
```